# How to fix Python Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to convert a date column of CSV file to a different type of calendar date.
when I specify the index value (i) as a number for a particular rowindex, it works fine but for the entire data frame, it gives me an error.

```
for i, row in df1.itertuples():
date_str=df1.iloc[i].name
dd,mm,yyyy=date_str.split('-', )
dd_int,mm_int,yyyy_int=int(dd),int(mm),int(yyyy)
new_date=indian_civil.from_gregorian(yyyy_int,mm_int,dd_int)
```

CSV file's first column has dates in Gregorian format, and I need in Indian civil format`(2016, 3, 28)=(1938, 1, 8)`
this conversion should happen for the entire date column

Comment: `for i, row in df1.itertuples()` what's `df1` ?

Comment: df1 = pd.read_csv(file_loc, index_col=0, na_values=['NA'], usecols=[0])

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of df1?

Comment: No. Post the output of df1.head()

Comment: Date
28-03-2016
29-03-2016
30-03-2016
31-03-2016
01-04-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["28-03-2016", "29-03-2016", "30-03-2016", "31-03-2016", "01-04-2016"])
df.columns = ["Date"]
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df

          Date
0   2016-03-28
1   2016-03-29
2   2016-03-30
3   2016-03-31
4   2016-01-04

from convertdate import indian_civil
df["indian_civil"] = df.apply(lambda x: indian_civil.from_gregorian(x.Date.year, x.Date.day, x.Date.month), axis=1)
df

          Date   indian_civil
0   2016-03-28  (1940, 1, 17)
1   2016-03-29  (1940, 2, 17)
2   2016-03-30  (1940, 3, 17)
3   2016-03-31  (1940, 4, 16)
4   2016-01-04  (1938, 1, 12)
```

Comment: df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date) gives me an error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: Are you sure you executed `df.columns = ["Date"]`

Comment: `df.Date` should be `df.whatever_your_date_column_name` is

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(file_loc, index_col=0, na_values=['NA'], usecols=[0])

Comment: and on df, i get Date
28-03-2016
29-03-2016
30-03-2016
31-03-2016
01-04-2016

Comment: If possible don't use `index_col=0`. Otherwise this should work `df["indian_civil"] = map(lambda x: indian_civil.from_gregorian(x.year, x.day, x.month), df.index)`

Comment: I need the converted date in datetime format and not as map

Comment: `df["indian_civil"] = pd.to_datetime(df.indian_civil.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(map(str, list(x)))))` should do

Comment: raised an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'year'